# Getting [ERR!] as output when trying to use the Nancy SuperSimpleViewEngine to render partials

Tags: c#, nancy

The example I'm using is literally the one from their example page here: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Super-Simple-View-Engine

So I have my files set up with `index.sshtml` and `master.sshtml` (copy/pasted verbatim from the example) in the root, and serving up the result with:

```
Get["/"] = result => View["index.sshtml"];
```

When I then go to visit localhost in my browser I get a text simply saying "[ERR!]", instead of the "This is content on the index page" which I had expected.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I have to explicitly do to enable the Master/Section functionality of the SSVE?

**Edit:**
Views:

master.sshtml

```
<html>
<body>
@Section['Content'];
</body>
</html>
```

index.shtml

```
@Master['master.sshtml']

@Section['Content']
   This is content on the index page
@EndSection
```

File structure:

```
+ Debug
|---ConsoleApplication1.exe
|---index.sshtml
|---master.sshtml
|---(rest of files Visual Studio outputs)
```

I'm pretty sure this is the simplest example that could possibly work, and for some reason, it doesn't. There are no (uncaught) exceptions thrown, not output in the debug window, and no other indications that something has gone awry, except for the [ERR!] being printed. It is the only content being printed, so I'm assuming it's something in the "Master" block that is failing...

Comment: You do not need to enable anything to make it work. It would help if you listed your view, your partial and the file structure you have for your views in your project

Comment: You where right. It turns out something was corrupting the master.sshtml file. When I copied the file manually, everything worked as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone else sees this, make sure that all .sshtml files are marked as **'Copy to Output Directory" : 'Copy Always'** under File Properties

Comment: I had to put the master.sshtml in the /Views folder.  It had it in a /Layouts folder and this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to:

1. Open the `sshtml` file in another text-editor, change the encoding to ``UTF-8 no BOM``` then
2. Remove the whitespace at first position "@Master['MasterPage']" (perhaps it was the UTF8-BOM?)
3. Save the file.
4. Go to Visual Studio, a dialog will notify you about the "external changes", click `Reload all` and everything should be good.